# Finding unused memory in process memory

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

I'm looking for a reliable way to find `unused memory` in a `C` program's process since I need to "inject" some data into somewhere without it corrupting anything.

Whenever I find an area with only zeros in it, that's a good sign. However, no guarantees: It can still crash. All the non-zero memory is most likely being used for sure so it cannot be overwritten reliably (most memory has some kind of data in it).

I understand that you can't really know (without having the application's source code for instance) but are there any heuristics that make sense such as choosing certain segments or memory looking a certain way? Since the data can be `200KB` this is rather large and finding an appropriate address range can be difficult/tedious.

Allocating memory via OS functions doesn't work in this context.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. What exactly is the context of your question?

Comment: @melpomene: The context is that this is the only way to make the application load my custom data since the file system cannot (as easily) be modified to do this due to encryption, packing and similar.

Comment: What is "this" and what is "the application" and what is "my custom data"?

Comment: How on earth do you plan to do it, and use the data. You need to modify the code to use the data. If you don’t have permission to modify, what you’re attempting is nefarious and not to be encouraged.

Comment: @melpomene: "This" is the method described above (inject into process memory), "the application" is someone else's C application using files and "my custom data" is the bytes representing a file to be used instead of a default one. I already know how to make the application load it. I just need the respective available memory to load the file's bytes into since finding that unused address range is troublesome. I guess this is enough explanation.

Comment: If you have so little control over this application, how are you going to get it to use the data you throw into it?  As stated above, this is an XY problem.  You need to get this process to use a different set of data than it's using now, and you've already decided on the solution.  And you've provided nowhere near enough details to solve your actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

Without deep knowledge of a remote process you cannot know that any memory that is actually allocated to that process is 'unused'.

Just finding writable memory (regardless of current contents) is asking to crash the process or worse.

Asking the OS to allocate some more memory in the other process is the way to go, that way you know the memory is not used by the process and the process won't receive that address through an allocation of its own.